# How To Fix String Index Out of Range in Python

Tags: python, index-error

I'm currently learning python. There is an exercise in the book which outlines code for decoding. I followed along with this code however I keep getting back an error in the middle of the program.

Here is the code that is causing the problem:

```
def decode(string_for_decoding):
    result = ""
    for i in range(0, len(string_for_decoding)):
        if string_for_decoding[i+1].isdigit():
            result += string_for_decoding[i] * int(string_for_decoding[i+1])
        elif string_for_decoding[i].isalpha():
            result += string_for_decoding[i]
    return result


string_for_decoding = input("Enter a string to decode: ")
print(decode(string_for_decoding))
```

Comment: Please post code as code (``` before and after the code block) instead of a screenshot. This makes it possible to copy/paste as well as google.

Comment: The length of your range function is one too big, try subtracting one from it

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: you are using `[i+1]` therefore, at the last letter of your word your algorithm is checking an additional letter which isnt existent. Therefore it raises this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the index from range is larger than the number of chars in the string.  It might look like this:

```
def decode(string_for_decoding: str):
    result = ""
    for i in range(0, len(string_for_decoding)):
        if len(string_for_decoding) > i + 1 and string_for_decoding[i + 1].isdigit():
            result += string_for_decoding[i] * int(string_for_decoding[i + 1])
        elif string_for_decoding.isalpha():
            result += string_for_decoding[i]
    return result

print(decode(input("Enter a string to decode: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get index `i+1` which cannot be equal or greater than `len(string)`.

Comment: but I have to check index i + 1. I know because of the this situation, I got that error but I can't fix it...

Comment: @Burak It is physically impossible to access a character after the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are going from `0 to len(string)` and inside `for` loop you are trying to access index: `i+1`
THis is the root cause! Either:

- iterate till one length less e.g. till `len(string) - 1`
- Or use indices
  inside appropriately

Moreover it is highly discouraged to use `range(len(x))`. You can simply iterate over any collective datatype as `for i in x:` If you want indices too have a look at [`enumerate()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/). And you can forget about index errors all together.